# how to set default value in backend form?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i generated admin in Symfony 1,4. I have there DoctrineChoice. I would like set this list select in action.class.php.

I copied executeNew to action.class.php, but i dont can set default value on load page.

```
$this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
$this->news = $this->form->getObject();
$this->form['author_id']->getWidget()->setOption('choices', '2');
```

doesnt work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

or just simply like this in lib/form

```
$this->setDefault('fieldname', $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$this->form['author_id']->getWidget()->setDefault(2);
```

But I have to say that if you want it clean, this code belong to the Form class, not the action.